# Run script at boot/startup in Ubuntu 12.04 x64 Server

Tags: boot, server, ssh, scripts, fedena

I am trying to start the RoR application named fedena.

What I generally do is SSH login as `root`and hit these commands

```
root@cloud:~# cd fedena
root@cloud:~/fedena# script/server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:7800
and so on...meaning the app server is running
```

Then when I close the SSH session, the application ends.

Now,what I figured out was for keeping it alive was to run this shell script through **webmin** interface and it survived. But, I wanted to autorun this script on every boot/restart.
I tried to add

```
./fedena/script/server
```

before the `exit 0` line in the

```
/etc/rc.local
```

Alas ! It didn't work. Why I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Given your script is bash and the path is `/root/fedina/server/script` you could have:

```
##!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

bash /root/fedina/server/script

exit 0
```

**Note:** Don't forget about the execution bits (eg. `chmod a+x /etc/rc.local`)

Comment: I tried bash /location/of/file but it didn't work. Later I realised my script is ruby script. I then did ruby /location/to/file and it worked. Thanks for the execution bit help @andy.holmes